# How to call Future method before StreamBuilder on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, future, stream-builder

I am trying to get the current user position before get the stream data using that info. So using Flutter `1.17.5` and `geolocator: ^5.3.2+2` I am getting the `Position`using the follow util class

```
class LocationProvider {

Future<Position> getPosition() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator()
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    return position;
  }
}
```

then I have to pass the info to `bloc` in order to retreive the Stream data with the marker

```
Widget _getAllProducts(ProductBloc productBloc, LocationProvider locationProvider) async{
Position position = locationProvider.getPosition();
var longitude = position.longitude;
var latitude = position.latitude;
int meter = 50;
productBloc.allByRange(meter, latitude, longitude);

return StreamBuilder(
  stream: productBloc.productsByRangeStream,
```

How ever I got this message

```
A value of type 'StreamBuilder<List<ProductModel>>' can't be returned from method '_getAllProducts' because it has a return type of 'Widget'
```

**Edit 1**

```
class ProductBloc {

Stream<List<ProductModel>> get productsByRangeStream =>
  _allByRangeProductsController.stream;



void allByRange(double range, double lat, double lon) async {
    final products = await _productFirebaseService.allByRange(range, lat, lon);
    _allByRangeProductsController.sink.add(products);
  }

}
```

How can I fix it??

Comment: What happens if `Widget _getAllProducts` is changed to `StreamBuilder<List<ProductModel>> _getAllProducts` ?

Comment: because I use it on ``return Scaffold(body: _getAllProducts(productBloc))`` and it recieve a widget

Comment: what's the builder function of  StreamBuilder

Comment: @D.R. call bloc method how call service method how return ``Future<List<ProductModel>>``